# add to favourite list in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have added the add to favorites list feature for each product on the product page of my website, and the user can add any product to their favorites list.
But if the user already adds this product to the favorites list, I want the word remove to be displayed instead of the word add, so that if he wants, he can remove that product from his favorite list.
But the following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'favourite'



# model

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_favourite')

# view

def product(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    is_favourite = False
    if products.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_favourite = True
    context = {'products': products, 'is_favourite': is_favourite}

#template

    {% if is_favourite %}
    <a  href="{% url 'home:favourite' product.id %}"> remove </a>
    {% else %}
     <a  href="{% url 'home:favourite' product.id %}"> add </a>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def add_product(request,pk):
     product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
     if request.user not in product.favourite.all():
         product.favourite.add(request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(' --the url that you want to redirect the 
                user --')

def remove_product(request,pk):
     product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
     if request.user in product.favourite.all():
         product.favourite.remove(request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(' --the url that you want to redirect the 
        user --')

def product(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products}
```

urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
     path('product/<int:pk>/add',views.add_product,name='add_product'),
     path('product/<int:pk>/remove',views.remove_product,name='remove_product'),
     ]
```

#template

```
 {% for product in products %}
     <!-- you should create a view for add and remove  -->
    {% if request.user in product.favourite.all %}
    <a  href="{% url 'home:remove_product' product.pk %}"> remove </a>
    {% else %}
     <a  href="{% url 'home:add_product' product.pk %}"> add </a>
    {% endif %}
 {% empty %}
 <h1>No products for now</h1>
{% endfor %}
```